# How to save inputed data in a textbox [EDITED]

Tags: plugins, php, code

This was asked before. I am re-posting it, edited.

So I am making a website using WordPress, and I wanted to make a text box that saves something that is typed in it. Let me explain:

1. Users (signed in) are presented with a textbox that asks them to input some data in a textbox.
2. When the user types in something, they can press the button "save", and the text is saved for that user. So no matter how much they refresh the page, what they typed is still in the textbox, and no other users can see what they typed.

I did some researching, and saw that "method=post" in HTML saves the inputed data that was typed in a form field to a web server, but it also stays on the site.

If I could get any help with how to code something like this in PHP or HTML, that would be great! THANKS!

EDIT: So I compiled some pictures of how the system would work, including some HTML on how it works. You can check it out here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J_vIdfUS5mhfWKrimPx0P2T_glJXrhShoj2XQiFDc4I/edit?usp=sharing

It seems pretty simple, but I think there needs to be some CSS and java that goes into the design of the textbox, or a Wrodpress plugin that needs to be coded to make such a thing work.

Comment: Please edit the original question, then it might be reopened.

Comment: I did; I re-edited the previous.